# Why i got ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Tags: javascript

Hello i try to make calculate function with `JavaScript`.
This is my code.

```
function DoAdd()
{
    //Get value1
 var Value1 = new Number(getElementById("Value1").value);
    //get value2
 var value2 = new Number(getElementById("Value2").value);
 //value1 + value2 
 document.getElementById("Result").setAttribute("value", Value1 + Value2);
}
Value1:
<input type="text" id="Value1" value="5">
</p>
<p>
Value2:
<input type="text" id="Value2" value="4">
</p>
<p>
Result:
<input type="text" value="" id="Result" readonly="true">
</p>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="DoAdd()" />
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="DoSub()" />
<input type="button" value="*" onclick="DoMul()" />
<input type="button" value="/" onclick="DoDiv()" />
```

This code gives me a error: `ReferenceError: getElementById` is not defined `DoAdd(), onclick().`

Where did I go wrong?

----Edit------

Do not forget to review the syntax in the languages ​​you use, as I have done.

Wrong:
-`var Value1 = new Number(getElementById("Value1").value);`
-`var value2 = new Number(getElementById("Value2").value);`

Fix:
-`var Value1 = new Number(document.getElementById("Value1").value);`
-`var value2 = new Number(document.getElementById("Value2").value);`

Comment: You should title your question better so that others with a similar problem can find a solution. Something like "How to fix Javascript ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined" would be more appropriate. I never understood why people are so quick to dislike questions instead of helping out a new member. It does no one any good. That being said, you should've Googled the error before asking it cause there's a billion answers already. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507650/why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-getelementbyid-is-not-defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `document.getElementById()`, as you have not locally defined a function called `getElementById()`.  You can take a look at more `document.getElementById()` syntax at the **[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)**.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix `getElementById` with `document`, e.g. `document.getElementById`