# Generate random fact from an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make a random fact generator website which would generate some random facts from an array, This is how I expected it to work - First I created a button which on click would generate a random fact but unfortunately The button is not working. Please check the code below and tell me the mistakes that I made.

### Code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Facts generator website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        
         <button id="btn" onclick="generateFacts()">Click me!</button>
         <div id="here">

         </div>
    </div>
<script>
    var facts = ["I will add more facts later" , 'Heaven']
    var randomFact = randomlist(facts);
    function generateFacts(){
        getElementById('here').innerHTML = randomFact;
    }
    function randomlist(list){
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        return list[x];
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507650/why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-getelementbyid-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

There is no function called `getElementById` alone. You need to use the method inside `document` object. So, the function will be `document.getElementById()`

```js
var facts = ["I will add more facts later", 'Heaven']
var randomFact = randomlist(facts);

function generateFacts() {
  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = randomFact;
}

function randomlist(list) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  return list[x];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Facts generator website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <button id="btn" onclick="generateFacts()">Click me!</button>
    <div id="here">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Another thing I would add to this answer is that you should probably declare the `randomFact` variable inside of the `generateFacts` function scope. That way you will get  a new random fact on every button click: `function generateFacts() { var randomFact = randomlist(facts);
  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = randomFact;
}`

Answer (score 0):

How about `document.getElementById()`?

```
function generateFacts(){
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = randomFact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open the developer console you should see the error that points out the mistake:

> The function getElementById is not defined.

So the function generateFacts should look like this:

```
function generateFacts(){
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = randomFact;
}
```

`document` is the owner of all the DOM elements of the page. So you should call it to help you find the element.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just new to programming and don't have much knowledge.